# Save checkbox values to database [ octobercms ]

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

How to save selected checkbox values as multiple records?

```
{% for record in enrol.records %}
   <tr>
    <td>
       <label class="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="child[]" value="{{ record.id }}"> ({{ record.id }}) {{ record.firstname }}
       </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my AJAX handler-
and this code gives an Error "Type error: Too few arguments to function"
this error displayed when I add `$child = $request->input(child[]);` and `onPayment(Request $request)` .

```
public function onPayment(Request $request) {

    //get the logged in user
    $user = Auth::getUser();

    //get the lesson id
    $eventId = $this->param('id');

    //get the child check box values
    $child = $request->input(child[]);

    if(is_array($child)) {
        $children = $child;
        foreach ($children as $players) {
            $enrolment = new Enrolment();
            $enrolment->lesson_id =  $eventId;
            $enrolment->child_id = $players;   //$user->id;
            $enrolment->save();
            }
        }
  Flash::success('You have been successfully enrolled in this event');
  return Redirect::back();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use your Ajax Handler method like this and it will work

```
public function onPayment() {
    //get the child check box values
    $child = post('child',[]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where you want to save. i thought you are having problem in collecting of child array.
please check if you are getting this or not.
$eventId = $this->param('id');

if not then try to send it with form input hidden field

Comment: of cause problem in collecting of child array. I tried your code then does not display an error and no data stored in DB as well. i'm getting this. $eventId = $this->param('id');

Comment: then there is definitely some problem in your code. please paste all the code of enrolement model or if you can send me complete link where I can download this all files related to this query and solve this issue